# 2 angular material cards next to each other?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I want to have 2 angular material cards next to each other but I don't know how.

**HTML**

```
<mat-card id="moth-card">
  <mat-card-title>Live Stats</mat-card-title>
  <app-card></app-card>
  <app-card></app-card>
</mat-card>
```

At the moment the second one is under the first one.

Comment: `display: block?`

Answer (score 3):

Try below CSS:

```
display: inline-block;
```

HTML Code:

```
<mat-card id="moth-card">
  <mat-card-title>Live Stats</mat-card-title>
 <mat-card class="inline-block">
   Part 1
 </mat-card>
 <mat-card class="inline-block">
   Part 2
 </mat-card>
</mat-card>
```

CSS:

```
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ca8wba)